# Displaying [][] using addRow () JTable

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans

Please help . I am writing a fairly extensive project, and I came across a problem that I can not solve.
I have a "`JFrame.setRows (tableName)`" method that returns a filled two-dimensional array.
I would like to display this array in Jtable.
Number of columns in Jtable == number of columns in "JFrame.setRows (tableName)";
I used the addRow () method;

```
 String[] sys=new String[x];
        for(q=0;q<9;q++){
           for(r=0;r<x;r++){
                 sys[r]=(String)JFrame.setRows(tableName)[r][q];
                 System.out.println(sys[r]);
               model.addRow(new String[]{sys[r]});

            }
        }
```

The result of my program is that the results of the table "`JFrame.setRows (tableName)`" [] [] are displayed in one Jtable column.
Can anyone improve my code?
Is there a better way to assign an array [][] to JTable (I'm using Netbeans)
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Your question and code are not fully clear, but it looks like you want to create a new TableModel with your data, so do that: create a new DefaultTableModel object, which you can do by passing in the 2D array along with a 1D array of column name Strings, and then set the JTable with that model.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense by the way: `JFrame.setRows(...)`. The JFrame class does not have any static method like this.

Comment: If you had to use DefaultTableModel's addRow, then you would use a single non-nested for-loop, and add each 1D array row via the `DefaultTableModel#addRow(...)` method

Comment: ...........hello? OK closing as duplicate.

Comment: thank you, that's it, I'll try to fix it